# Integration of the absolute value of an unknown function

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value

I'm doing a vector arclength problem, and have gotten to the part where I have $\int | r'(t) | dt.  $

Both $r(t)$ and $r'(t)$ are unknown functions, though I do know that $0 \leq r(t)$ for $a ≤ t ≤ b$.

I now that I would normally integrate by dividing the integral into two parts such as when I'm given a definite integral, but since $r'(t)$ can very well be negative at any point, I'm not sure currently?  It's probably something stupid that I'm forgetting anyways, but thanks anyways.

Comment: What do you need to prove/compute/estimate/accomplish overall? Even if you knew when $r'(t)$ was negative, you still wouldn't be able to exactly compute $\int|r'(t)|dt$ since, as you say, $r,r'$ are unknown.

Comment: I'm just showing the arclength of a vector in terms of $r'(t)$ and $r(t)$, obviously $r'(t)$ will integrate into $r(t)+C$.  For reference, $x(t)=r(t)cos(t)$ and $y(t)=r(t)sin(t)$.  So when finding arc length the $cos(t)$ and $sin(t)$ obviously cancel out into 1, leaving us with $(((r'(t))^2)^.5$, in other words the integral of $|r'(t)|$.  And thanks for fixing my formatting error in the op.

Comment: Be careful- when you compute $x'(t),y'(t)$ you have to use the product rule, so (for example) $x' = r'\cos(t) - r\sin(t)$. Once you put everything in an integral, I think you are done; if you don't have any more information about $r$ or $r'$ then the best you can do is say 'arclength = this integral'.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  You're right, I was treating it as a constant for some reason when I was deriving it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problems, and don't worry - we all have our moments (I'm certainly no exception)